# Prevent 'wheel' event scrolling if element has basic scroll

Tags: javascript

I've built custom scrolling on my page through `wheel` event on `window`. However it shoots even when I want to scroll the element with basic scrollbar. How to disable `wheel` event on this element, but be able to scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in the event handler if the element is scrollable

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    if ( event.target.scrollHeight < event.target.clientHeight ) {
          // scollheight less than clientheight, means it doesn't have scrollbars ...
          // do stuff                                
    }
})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that wheel event is called on window object. Will this work in this condition?

Comment: @MaxelRus - It will, but then you'd have to check the target element instead of `this` for scrollbars

Comment: Note that `event.target` is the element the event originates at, if you have nested elements within the element with the scrollbar you might have to recreate some sort of `closest()` functionality to get the parent element that has the scrollbars etc.

Comment: Should be a `<=` comparison, or at least that's what worked for me (modern Chrome, FF). All items w/out a scrollbar seem to report equal heights.  That includes if `overflow: hidden` is set and the content does actually overflow (it would have a scrollbar if `overflow: auto` was used).